# How to write FQL for wall fetching values in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am integrating facebook api in my application. I can login perfectly and able to post text on wall. I want to trace my all wall values. I am seeing a query is written in my application which is

```
NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = %lld  limit 50",_session.uid];
```

but this query is returning only those wall value which is posted through the application.

Can anybody help me, how to get wall posted values by FQL and also where can I get FQL statements different queries ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902131/retrieve-my-wall-post-in-my-native-i-phone-application) of SO.

For other list of FQL queries you can follow [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

Comment: but this query is returning only those wall value which is posted through the application